# I may go to the party - permission or possibility? Or both?

Tags: meaning, differences, phrase-meaning, modal-verbs, sentence-meaning

Hope you can help me to answer this tricky question. I´m posting here as I got the impression that it needs a linguist or at least a native to answer it.

When you say: ***I may go to the party.*** Does this mean that you have permission to go there? Kind of - your mum allowed you to go there... or does it mean that you´ll probably go there? I´d say it´s the second case.

Or: ***I may play the guitar.*** I´d understand that the person means that there is a probability that they will play the guitar. Just as when you say the same thing by using "might".

I use may just to ask for permission or to give permission to somebody.

So, I´d say I´m allowed to go to the party/to play the guitar if I want to express that **I (!!)** have permission to do something.

I did a lot of research, but examples with MAY are always:

a) **questions** - May I take a seat?

b) using **YOU** - you may leave the room once you´ve finished the exam.

I´d really appreciate it if you could give me more information about this issue.

Comment: The meaning depends entirely on context. "Mum says I may go to the party." "I _may_ go to the party if I get back from London in time."

Comment: _May_ is a modal, and all modals have at least two meanings, called _epistemic_ (logical: _This may be the place_) and _deontic_ (permission/obligation: _You may attend if you're back by midnight_).

Comment: @fumblefingers That excellent answer does not answer this question.